# What makes the Gmail API more efficient than IMAP?

Tags: imap, gmail-api

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).  One of the [stated benefits](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/06/introducing-new-gmail-api.html) of the Gmail API is that it can "deliver dramatic performance improvements over IMAP." What aspects of the Gmail API and protocol allow it to be more efficient than IMAP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example IMAP has the notion of a "mailbox" and supporting that means storing a sequence number for every message.  In Gmail's IMAP, since every label is a folder that means we need to keep a sequence of every message in every label.  For something like 'All Mail' that could be 1,000,000 messages--hard to keep track of that in the server.

Things like threads, are also foreign to IMAP but native in Gmail.  The Gmail backend is optimized to support threads as is the Gmail API.  If you want to retrieve all messages in a thread it's a single call in the API.

The dramatic performance improvements is for the use-cases where the API makes sense (like web and mobile applications).  If you want to sync the entire mailbox, IMAP may well offer as good, or better, performance given the ability to cache an authenticated connection, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to answer this is to compare the [Gmail API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) with the [IMAP protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) and see what kinds of operations they permit. Anything that lets you

- do more work server-side instead of client-side,
- use fewer round trips,
- send and receive only the particular data you're interested in, or
- cache state locally

is going to give performance improvements.

Some specific examples: (I've merely dabbled in IMAP and have no experience with Gmail API, so my examples may not be valid. Like I said, [read](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) the [docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) for the full story.)

- The Gmail API has built-in support for [synchronizing clients](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync), including getting a list of recent updates. Doing this in IMAP is [harder](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4549.txt).
- Gmail API's [searching](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) features appear to be more powerful than [IMAP's](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4).
- Gmail API's support for [threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads) appears to be higher-level than IMAP's optional [THREAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256) extension.

Comment: In some ways, the difference is that an IMAP is a bit of an impedance match for Gmail, in that it really doesn't match how their system is set up, while the Gmail API allows you to deal with things directly.  Eg.  Gmail API gives you direct access to GMail Threads and Labels, where as in IMAP they're provided as nonstandard extensions or through hacks (eg, Labels as Folders).

Comment: IMAP, as used by gmail, has fine support for synchronizing clients. BTDT. Gmail's IMAP threading is also fine. Try it, you'll like it. The big difference is that in the gmail API, messages live in threads and a "mailbox" is more or less a collection of threads. In IMAP, messages live in mailboxes and threads are a collection of messages. That difference makes quite a bit of difference to the design of a client. You can write good code to both interfaces, but it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason Gmail API is much more efficient is because it only needs to download each message once.

With IMAP, each message must get downloaded and indexed multiple times, once for each Gmail label (i.e., IMAP folder).

A [post at Metaspike](https://community.metaspike.com/t/collecting-gmail-api-or-imap/265) has identified those differences and more, including around authentication and data types.